# Node list control

Tags: nodes

I am using Drupal 7.

For example, I do not want to show node uid=28 in the list ($page==0).
The list page is a "view" without filtering there. So it shows up all the nodes of a specific
content type (I only filter with this content type in view setting).

With this function, I can change its title.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->uid == 28) {
    $node->title = "Do not show me!!!";
    $node = NULL;
    unset($node);
  }
}
```

But I could not work out how to not show up this node at all in the list.
I do not want to implement some filtering in view part.

This does not work.

```
$node = NULL;
unset($node);
```

I like to use hook_node_view and set more complicated filter logic there.

So basically I like to:
implement a view page with only filtering to specific content type that I want;
implement a more complicated filtering/selecting method in hook_node_view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question. You have created a `view` containing nodes of a special content-type and now you would like to exclude a node with `nid` equal to 28 from the results? If this is the case then I think you ***should*** add a new filter of type `Content:nid` and set it to `not equal` 28 in your views configuration page.

Also, I don't think the `hook_node_view()` can be used to filter the results for a view. You can use the hook to modify or add/remove elements from the node before it's being rendered.

[Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7) is a list of all views hooks.

For example you could use the `hook_views_query_alter()` to add a new filter to the query.